# How can I append to a particular row using text file in JAVA?

Tags: java, arraylist

The system I'm creating for my project would be a Course Registration System in Java.

The problem I'm facing right now is how can I append to a particular row (we can say refer to the student ID) so that the registration code modules would be behind the line after the comma.

Every time when I tried to append, it would always append to the last line of the file.

An example of the text file:
[image: Example of the text file]

After the registration of modules, I would also need to display all modules of that particular student row for that specific subject.

I'm been researching about the solution to come off.
Some say it would be easier to implement the arrayList->File / writing and reading data from the file.

Could anyone help me solve this problem?

Comment: show us whatever you have tried till now, perhaps an example of i/p and o/p will help us to know more about your issue

Comment: You cannot just insert text into a section of a file. The simplest thing to do would be to just rewrite the whole file with the updated text.

Comment: @matt Yes. How could I do that? I think rewriting the whole file with updated text is the best option. But how do i store the previous text so it wont erase after rewriting?

Comment: @AmeyYadav How can I show you the example of i/p and o/p of my project?

Comment: The solution by @matt is the right way. You can store the text in memory and in the file. At the startup, the application read the entire file. Every change in memory can be then transferred to the file for persistence (you can adopt other kinds of policy also).

Comment: @Sandro For example in the text.txt, I would like to append the modules code behind the 0327159 (first line) of the code so it would look like behind there have some codes. How can i store all the elements of the file and output back before rewriting the whole structure

Comment: @OliverSim: you have to decide a data structure to use in memory and then serialise this last one in the file. Maybe a JSON file format can be more useful.

Comment: I've posted an answer with a cleaner approach, please consider once

Comment: @Chiranjib Alright. Thanks for your time and help to solve my problem. In fact, I might stick with matt way of approach because my lecturer havent taught us JSON yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First read in your file.

```
List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("/path/to/your/file.txt"), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

Then find and modify your line, in this example I modify the line that starts with "0327159".

```
List<String> toWrite = new ArrayList<>();

for(int i = 0; i<lines.size(); i++){
    String line = lines.get(i);
    if(line.startsWith("0327159")){
        String updated = line.trim() + ", more text\n";
        toWrite.add(updated);
    } else{
        toWrite.add(line);
    }
}
```

So now `toWrite` has all of the lines that you want to write to your file.

```
Files.write(
    Paths.get("/path/to/outfile.txt"), 
    toWrite, 
    StandardCharsets.UTF_8, 
    StandardOpenOptions.CREATE, 
    StandardOpenOptions.TRUNCATE_EXISTING );
```

Comment: It seems that i have problems with using Paths. and StandardCharset. as it says cannot find symbol

Comment: @OliverSim which java are you using? Also, it is `StandardCharsets` with an 's'

Comment: Yes. solved the StandardCharsets. But for the .get method , it still shows cannot find symbol

Comment: @OliverSim [Paths](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Paths.html) definitely has a method get. Are you using the 's' at the end?

Comment: God damn it. I forgot to input all the libraries. Yes. Gonna try it now. Big thanks matt!!!

Comment: Can i know What does the i==specialCase does? Give me an example for the id code 0327159

Comment: You have to decide what the special case is. Ill update the code to follow your example.

Comment: It doesn't seems to work when I insert the if(lines.contains("0327159")) to append the ,more text line. and i cant use the startswith method

Comment: Why can't you use "startsWith" also, why doesn't it work if you use contains?

Comment: @OliverSim you don't use `lines.contains` that would check the list, you use `line.constains` that checks the individual string. That is also why you cannot use `startsWith` because it is a string method.

Comment: Thank you Matt! Really appreciate your time and help that I need. Solved my problem already. It seems that ArrayList is very dynamic to use in File I/O. Now how do I read existing student ID so i can output all the modules registered?

Comment: You could follow the same logic. Read the file, look for the line that contains the ID, then when you find that line print it out. Or the parts of it you want.

Comment: Which is by using the arrayList logic to get the particular line using .get method and print out the modules? Okay.

Comment: Sounds ok. You can use get, you can use a for-each loop. You just need to go through and check each line. Then when you find the correct line, process it.

Comment: By the way, one most last question about the displaying of all modules registered. For example, I've written another text file, and inside the text file of line no.3: 

123123,PRJ60207,ITS61703,ITS62204,CSC60304,CSC60403,CSC60303

How can i ignore the student ID of 123123 and just print out the module codes? So it would loook like this

Comment: Modules Registered: PRJ60207,ITS61703,ITS62204,CSC60304,CSC60403,CSC60303

Comment: Personally, I would say. `String[] fields = line.split(",")` now fields contain all of your information. Then you can loop over fields but skip the first element, which contains your id.

Comment: So the `code`String [] fields = line.split(",") `code` is inside the line.contains(id) ? I would get this error [Ljava.lang.String;@42a57993

Comment: Alright I know what you meant and implemented in my code already. It works wonderfully. Tq @matt for guiding me and giving me valuable information to solve my problem. Really appreciate your help. I've learnt my mistakes from coding. I would buy you a cup of coffee for a treat :)

Comment: Hey Matt! One more question. are you still there?

Answer (score 0):

You should really try a JSON based approach, to make it less clumsy and eliminate confusion. Here's a working example. My code adds a new student every time and adds a new module to existing students every time. The code is not really optimized since this is just for illustration

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

public class ModuleRegistration
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        File file = new File("C:\\MyStudents.txt");
        if (!file.exists())
            file.createNewFile();

        List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get(file.getAbsolutePath()));
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        List<StudentInfo> newLines = new ArrayList<StudentInfo>(2);
        for (String line : lines)
        {
            StudentInfo info = mapper.readValue(line, StudentInfo.class);
            String modules = info.getModules() == null ? "" : info.getModules();
            if (!"".equals(modules))
                modules += ",";
            modules += "Module" + System.currentTimeMillis();
            info.setModules(modules);
            newLines.add(info);
        }
        StudentInfo info = new StudentInfo();
        long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
        info.setId(time);
        info.setModules("Module" + time);
        info.setName("Name" + time);
        info.setPassword("Password" + time);
        info.setType("Local");
        newLines.add(info);

        try (FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(file, false);)
        {
            for (StudentInfo i : newLines)
            {
                writer.write(i.toString());
                writer.write(System.lineSeparator());
            }
        }

        System.out.println("Done");
    }

    static class StudentInfo
    {
        @JsonProperty("id")
        private long id;

        @JsonProperty("password")
        private String password;

        @JsonProperty("name")
        private String name;

        @JsonProperty("type")
        private String type;

        @JsonProperty("modules")
        private String modules;

        // getters and setters

        @Override
        public String toString()
        {
            try
            {
                return new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(this);
            }
            catch (JsonProcessingException exc)
            {
                exc.printStackTrace();
                return exc.getMessage();
            }
        }
    }
}
```